# why using x in list and change x's value did not work in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list nums = [1,3,2,5,6] and I want to subtract each element's value by 1. Now I wrote codes like

```
for i in nums:
    i -= 1
```

However, when I print nums its values did not change. I'm wondering why it doesn't work, and whether there is an elegant way in Python to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is a local variable and does not reflect the actual objects in `nums`, only their values. The best way to do this is to use a list comprehension:

```
nums = [i - 1 for i in nums]
```

If you need to retain references to `nums`:

```
nums[:] = = [i - 1 for i in nums]
```

Demo:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [i - 1 for i in nums]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop sets `i` to successive values in the list, not references into the list. There are a couple ways to accomplish what you want:

```
nums = [i-1 for i in nums]
```

Is one way. If you need to keep the same list object you could do:

```
for ndx in xrange(len(nums)):
    nums[ndx] -= 1
```

Comment: `range` if using Python 3.

Comment: Visualize this with http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=nums%20%3D%20list%28range%285%29%29%0Afor%20i%20in%20nums%3A%0A%20%20%20%20i%20-%3D%201&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false